# how get actual file path from file chooser using intent

Tags: android, file-upload

how to get file path using intent. I am using this code  to choose the file

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
 intent.setType("*/*"); 
// intent.setData(uri);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   try {
        startActivityForResult(
         Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
       } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
       {// Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
```

now i want to get actual file path in

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                        && data != null) {
    Uri selectedFile = data.getData();


                String[] filePathColum = {  };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFile,
                        filePathColum, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColum[0]);

                String FilePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

but when i try to get  file path it crashed
how i get file path

Comment: when i pick file  it crashed